# Simplifying covariance expression, don't understand steps in between

Tags: covariance

Can anyone explain the steps in between? 
In particular I don't understand:

1) How the $n$ became part of the final result. Does this $n$ just denote the total number of observations? Does it iterate over the number of observations like $i$ does?

2) When I expand the parentheses in the first equation I get 4 terms, how does it end up being only 2 terms?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}{n-1}\\=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_iY_i-X_i\bar{Y}-\bar{X}Y_i+\bar{X}\bar{Y})}{n-1}\\=\frac{\sum_i^nX_iY_i-\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\bar{Y}-\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}Y_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}\bar{Y}}{n-1}$$

Now the key is you should treat $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ as constants within the $\sum$ operator.

Now just look at the last three terms in the numerator

$-\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\bar{Y}=-\bar{Y}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=-\bar{Y}*n\bar{X}=-n\bar{X}\bar{Y}$

Note $(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=n*\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}=n\bar{X})$

By the same calculation

$-\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}Y_i=-n\bar{X}\bar{Y}$

The last term

$\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}\bar{Y}=n\bar{X}\bar{Y}$

Add them together you will get your answer.